# Why do I get these syntax errors?

Tags: c

I have the task of writing a LinkedList, without using loops. Anyways, this is my code:

The structs in the header file:

```
typedef struct Node
{
    Node* last;
    Node* next;
    int val;
}Node;

typedef struct LinkedList
{
    Node* first;
    Node* last;
    int sum;
    int length;
}LinkedList;
```

In the errors below it says that Node and LinkedList are not known and I don't understand why.

```
Node* new_node(int val)
{
    Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->last = NULL;
    node->val = val;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

LinkedList* new_list(int val)
{
    LinkedList* list = (LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    Node* node = (Node*)new_node(val);
    list->first = node;
    list->last = node;
    list->length = 1;
    list->sum = val;
    return list;
}

void delete_list(LinkedList* list)
{
    Node* node;
    Node* next;

    node = list->first;
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        next = node->next;
        free(node);
        node = next;
    }
    free(list);
}

void set_next(LinkedList* list, Node* node)
{
    list->last->next = node;
    list->last = node;
    list->length++;
    list->sum += node->val;
}

void delete_node(LinkedList* list,  Node* node)
{
    node->last->next = node->next;
    node->next->last = node->last;
    list->length--;
    list->sum -= node->val;
    free(node);
}

int size(LinkedList* list)
{
    return list->length;
}

Node* get_first(LinkedList* list)
{
    return list->first;
}

Node* get_last(LinkedList* list)
{
    return list->last;
}

Node* get_next(Node* node)
{
    return node->next;
}

Node* get_last(Node* node)
{
    return node->last;
}

int get_val(Node* node)
{
    return node->val;
}

int get_avg(LinkedList* list)
{
    return list->sum / list->length;
}
```

My problem is that I get tons of errors about syntax and I don't understand why:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Can someone tell me why I get these errors?

Comment: From imbalanced `{` braces `}` or a redundant `;` ? It would need the *whole code* to identify.

Comment: I think this might be due to the duplicate naming.
Have you tried `typedef struct {} Node;`?

Comment: The member of `struct Node` named `Node* last;` needs to be `struct Node* last;` etc. It hasn't been typedeffed at that point.

Comment: Furthermore, C does not support overloading. You can either have `get_last(LinkedList *)` or `get_last(Node *)`, but not both. You could have `getLastNode` though.

Comment: Which is the first error it reports? Usually everything past the first one is just 'follow up'. (And if it's a different issue, it will come up again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in this code that I can spot right now.
The first one has already been stated by Weather Vane:

In your declaration of Node, you are referencing itself, which is fine, but the typedef is yet incomplete at this point.

That means, you need to put `struct` in front of the name to identify the structure.

```
typedef struct Node
{
    struct Node* last;
    struct Node* next;
    int val;
} Node;
```

The second issue is, that you have two instances of `get_last` with different parameters.
C does not support overloading (whereas C++ does). As such, you will need to pick unique names, which best express what you are trying to get, such as: `getLastNode` and `getLastElement`.

Comment: Indeed worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The type used by a `typedef` isn't visible until the compiler reaches the final semi colon here: `}Node;`. Until that point, the type isn't known.

However, when using a *struct tag* such as done here `struct Node`, you can refer to that tag from within the struct definition itself. Simply add the `struct` keyword:

```
typedef struct Node
{
    struct Node* last;
    struct Node* next;
    int val;
}Node;
```

But from there on you'll be able to use `Node` without `struct`, because it is now a known typedef.

Answer (score 1):

1. type `Node` is not known at this point. It has to be:

```
typedef struct Node
{
    struct Node* last;
    struct Node* next;
    int val;
}Node;
```

2. You have duplicate `get_last` function definition. Delete one.

And it will compile OK

https://godbolt.org/z/PcjWMjdj9